# How to fit non-linear mixed model for count data?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, nonlinear-regression, count-data

I have been reading [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6776701/) and its supplemental coding materials on how to fit a non-linear mixed model for a use case that is very close to a use case I am interested in modeling:

```r
nlme(emaintent ~ theta1 + theta2*exp(theta3*n..ij - 
      theta4*dtime..ij), data=temp,
      fixed=list(theta1 ~ 1 + blsmk.never + gender + 
          minority + weekend, theta2 ~ 1 ,
          theta3 ~ 1 + blsmk.never,
          theta4 ~ 1 + blsmk.never),
          random=list(subid = 
                  list(theta1 ~ 1, theta2 ~ 1)),
             start=list(fixed=mcoef ),
             control=list(maxIter=10000)
)
```

They use the nlme package in R to model a non-linear model to handle exponential decaying effect of exposures on a response variable. This sounded great to me at first, but my data (confidential, but can synthesize a new dataset if required) is count data which I realize requires special handling that I am not sure is yet implemented in the nlme package. When I model using a Generalized Linear Mixed model using glmmTMB, I obtain a fairly good fit with no over-dispersion.

If you download the two supplemental files linked at the bottom of the paper, you can run the above model. But if you plot (or just read about) the distribution of the response data they use, it is obvious that it is not normally distributed. In fact, it is bounded by 0-10 (by definition, response variable is average of several scores that range from 0-10). Is this problematic if the model assumes residuals are normally distributed?

Would it be ok to use this similar nlme framework if the response variable were instead discrete and Poisson distributed?

If no, what are some libraries I can use to achieve this model in the least amount of pain as possible? I have a master's in statistics, but I am self-taught when it comes to non-linear models.

Thank you for reading

Comment: This is a common misconception: the normality assumption is about the residuals, not the response. I downloaded the supplementary data and fitted the model. Then I extracted the residuals with `r = resid(mod2)` and made a normal QQ plot with `qqnorm(r); qqline(r)`. The QQ plot doesn't suggest issues (with this particular assumption).